# Continuous Monitoring of a function in Java on a single thread

Tags: java, scheduledexecutorservice

I have a method in a particular class for which I need subsequent executions to take place at approximately regular intervals separated by the specified period. I need to do this using a `ScheduledExecutorService`.

Also, even when this method gets called multiple times from anywhere, I want the same thread to be executed without starting a new thread.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Use single threaded executor, and  `Executors#newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()` to create executor service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create an implementation class of Runnable(Make it singleton)

   ```
   public class MainTask implements Runnable {

       private static MainTask mainTask;

       private MainTask(){ }

       public static MainTask getInstance(){
           if(mainTask==null){
               mainTask = new MainTask();
           }
           return mainTask;
       }

       @Override
       public void run() {
           // task to run goes here
           System.out.println("Hello !! " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
       }

   }
   ```
2. Make use of scheduleAtFixedRate's method of 
   [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) method in order to execute the task at regular intervals separated by specified period.

   Its method definition is

   **ScheduledFuture scheduleAtFixedRate(Runnable command,
                                    long initialDelay,
                                    long period,
                                    TimeUnit unit)**

   where 
   ***period*** = period between successive executions. 
   Note that this value could be min/hrs/days etc depending on TimeUnit configured.
3. As this feature is something you would want it to be used by other classes I suggest you can encapsulate the thread creation and task creation in another class and allow it to be used by Class.methodName for.e.g MyScheduler.execute();

   ```
    public class MyScheduler {

       private static ScheduledExecutorService service;

       private static MainTask mainTask;

       static {
           service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
           mainTask = MainTask.getInstance();
       }

       public static void execute() {
           service.scheduleAtFixedRate(mainTask, 0, 4, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Looks good. But suppose i call MyScheduler.execute() multiple times, will it still use the same thread for mainTask or will it create a new one?

Comment: If you see the static block, I have made use of `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()` which would create a thread pool consisting of single thread which would be reused.